# Change firstname/lastname sortorder in Outlook and WindowsMobile

Tags: windows-mobile, outlook, contacts

I have been using Microsoft Outlook and WindowsMobile devices for some years now. But I keep getting frustrated about the way the "contact manager" adds new contacts. It always puts the "lastname" first as if thats a global-standard for every Outlook/Windowsmobile user?

I want to edit/change/setup the default way a new contact is added/shown in the contacts overview. I can add the contact manually, but after entering name, address phone, e-mail, www etc. it states that it will be archived as "[Lastname], [Firstname]" ...

Anyone out there who has come up with a solution or do we REALLY have to examine the iPhone/Android OS to get rid of this "bug"?

Note: Yes, I can manually edit the way its show each time I add a contact, but the trouble is that this is plain annoying - I want to edit the template or code something that change this behaviour of the "archiving" function. Not manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it is possible :) Contact changer will help you.

http://marketplace.windowsphone.com/details.aspx?appSKU=af5afa18-64db-4f55-9c67-5b010ac18a21

Comment: Okay, I havent tested it yet, but I mark the answer as correct so far. Hope thats okay.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Mobile contacts have a [FileAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909290.aspx) property determining the string that the contact is filed under. If you're asking how to do the whole thing programmatically, it shouldn't be to hard to implement it.

If that's not what you mean, this question would be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Comment: I use the danish language and translated "FileAs" is exactly what I have to do manually everytime. What I want to do is to hear about how to change this programtically, as I don't believe there is a setting anywhere in Outlook nor WindowsMobile that will allow me this change globally.

I was hoping for some Outlook/WindowsMobile coding ideas from experienced developers, if possible.